# ¿Cómo obtener data-attributes con FormBuilder Angular?

Tags: angular, data-atributos

Necesito agregar una id como data-attribute a mi input , pero no puedo encontrar la manera de resolverlo.

```
<input matInput formControlName=“nombre” [attr.data-idQuestion]=“1”
```

intente esto , pero no funciona

```
this.FirstFormGroup.get(‘nombre’).getAttribute(‘data-idQuestion’)
```

Help me

Comment: Listo, ya la hice en español

Comment: No, tampoco funciona :(

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder al elemento por medio de un formulario reactivo. Pero Angular te brinda la posibilidad de hacerlo por medio de la manipulación segura del DOM. Asigna un identificador con un `#` en el HTML para que pueda bindearse con el .ts

**component.html**

```
<input #nombre matInput formControlName="nombre" [attr.data-idQuestion]="1">
```

Ahora usemos el decorador [@viewChild()](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description) y capturamos el identificador asignado del HTML. Ahora si puedes usarlo, el decorador estará pendiente de los cambios en el identificador, ya tu sabrás el momento oportuno de utilizar el elemento.

**component.ts**

```
nombre @viewChild('nombre'): elementRef;

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.nombre.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-idQuestion'));
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias , me sirvio

Comment: Recuerda marcar como correcta para que otros devs puedan guiarse si tienen un problema similar al tuyo.